# Writing formula in VBA results in Type Mismatch 13

Tags: excel, vba

Overlying question: Is it possible to code formulas in VBA that save the values as a variable, without putting them in a cell on the worksheet?

I get the error for the line starting with "My_Date = Left(Replace" ... I assume it will also be an issue for the "My_Take = Right(Replace" line.

The function is supposed to take numbers out of strings:

```
Public Function SplitText(pWorkStr As String, pIsNumber As Boolean) As String

Dim xLen As Long
Dim xStr As String
xLen = VBA.Len(pWorkStr)
For i = 1 To xLen
    xStr = VBA.Mid(pWorkStr, i, 1)
    If ((VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) And pIsNumber) Or (Not (VBA.IsNumeric(xStr)) And Not (pIsNumber))) Then
        SplitText = SplitText + xStr
    End If
Next
End Function
```

This formats the numbers as a date and take without any letters:

```
Sub Fill_Date_and_Take()

    Dim NAMEoFILE As String

    Dim My_Date As String
    Dim My_Take As String

    NAMEoFILE = "I love dogs 09-20-17 Take Number 2.xlsx"

    My_Date = Left(Replace(Replace(Replace(SplitText(NAMEoFILE, True), 2, 0, "-"), 5, 0, "-"), 8, 0, "_"), 7)
        MsgBox (My_Date)

    My_Take = Right(Replace(Replace(Replace(SplitText(NAMEoFILE, True), 2, 0, "-"), 5, 0, "-"), 8, 0, "_"), 1)
        MsgBox (My_Take)

End Sub
```

Comment: You are passing `"-"` to the `Start` argument of the [`Replace` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/replace-function). It expects a `Long`.

Comment: As a side note, the big condition inside `SplitText` can be simplified to `If VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) = pIsNumber Then`.

Comment: Hi Gserg, Thanks for your help! I was hoping to use the "-","-", and "_" to format that date and take. When I run it in a cell, it works. Do you know why it wouldnt in the VBA code? ... in a cell it says Replace(old text, start number, number of characters, new text) which is why I had it formatted like that.

Comment: Because [Excel's `REPLACE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPLACE-REPLACEB-functions-8d799074-2425-4a8a-84bc-82472868878a) has nothing to do with [VBA's `Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/replace-function)? In any case, [neither of those](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) are the right choice to format a date.

Comment: I did not realize those were different! When I recorded a macro of the cell, it gave me what you see above. Maybe explaining a bit more on what I want will help: I am running this on multiple files, and need to get the date and take from each filename (workbook name) and save them as variables to use later on. Is there code in VBA that does the same thing as the Excel Replace?

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Replace()`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit new to Stack Overflow so I wasnt sure how to set GSerg's comment to the answer, but all I had to do was change each "Replace" to "WorksheetFunction.Replace"!

```
My_Date = Left(WorksheetFunction.Replace(WorksheetFunction.Replace(WorksheetFunction.Replace(SplitText(NAMEoFILE, True), 2, 0, "-"), 5, 0, "-"), 8, 0, "_"), 7)

My_Take = Right(WorksheetFunction.Replace(WorksheetFunction.Replace(WorksheetFunction.Replace(SplitText(NAMEoFILE, True), 2, 0, "-"), 5, 0, "-"), 8, 0, "_"), 1)
```

Thank you GSerg!!